# How to get the Type that describes an array of a base type?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, types

I need to create a **Type** instance for an array of a base type with a specified number of indexes. Essentially I need to method like the following that I can call...

```
public Type GetArrayOfType(Type baseType, int numOfIndexes)
{
    return /* magic does here */
}
```

So that calling the function would give the following result...

```
GetTypeArray(typeof(bool), 1) == typeof(bool[])
GetTypeArray(typeof(bool), 2) == typeof(bool[,])
GetTypeArray(typeof(bool), 3) == typeof(bool[,,])
```

The only solution I can come up with is the following...

```
public Type GetArrayOfType(Type baseType, int numOfIndexes)
{
    List<int> indexes = new List<int>();
    for(int i=0; i<numOfIndexes; i++)
        indexes.Add(1);

    return Array.CreateInstance(baseType, indexes.ToArray()).GetType();
}
```

This does work but having to create an instance of the required type in order to then call **GetType()** does not seem ideal. There must be a way to generate the **Type** without creating an instance. Or is there?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
public Type GetArrayOfType(Type baseType, int numOfIndexes) {
    return numOfIndexes == 1 ? baseType.MakeArrayType() : baseType.MakeArrayType(numOfIndexes);
}
```

There is a little trick there: although you can pass `1` to `MakeArrayType(int)`, the type that it is going to produce will *not* be the same as that returned by `MakeArrayType`. Here is an excerpt from the documentation:

> The common language runtime makes a distinction between vectors (that is, one-dimensional arrays that are always zero-based) and multidimensional arrays. A vector, which always has only one dimension, is not the same as a multidimensional array that happens to have only one dimension. You cannot use this method overload to create a vector type; if *`rank`* is `1`, this method overload returns a multidimensional array type that happens to have one dimension. Use the `MakeArrayType()` method overload to create vector types.

Comment: For why `MakeArrayType(1)` is not the same as `MakeArrayType()`, see the documentation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w0ykk2sw.aspx

Comment: Many thanks. Sometimes you just know there must be a better way.

Comment: @TimS. Thank you very much! I edited the answer to include the description from the docs.